# Django: OneToOneField has no attribute model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create profile system where my users django username will be their username on the site, and also allow them to create a bio. However when I try to migrate, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Here is my models.py files:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=user)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s's profile" % self.user

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

# Signal while saving user
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

And here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from profiles.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["user"]

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: `OneToOneField` is `unique` by definition. You can omit that parameter.

Comment: You should show the full traceback. Where exactly is that error happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try without importing the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth`.

Remove (or comment out) the `User` import line, the signal binding, and switch to string based model specification of relation in `OneToOneField`. The example of string based relation specification can be found [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

This looks like a circular dependency thing.

If you'd still get an error, try to remove stuff you don't need from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Still doesnt work when I comment out `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` As for my INSTALLED_APPS all I have is the defaults, the profiles app thats the problem and, another app, that I got to work fine. I'm not sure if this will help, but[ here is a more detailed error message](http://pastebin.com/ttKHDUe5).